# Can cakephp's inflector slug ignore specified characters?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, slug

What I'm trying to achieve is:

Let inflector slug Ignore a special character in a string, which would normally be replaced by the replacement string by inflector slug.

E.g.
Character I want to be ignored: '/'

Input: this is an /example/

Output: this_is_an_example

Output I want: this_is_an_/example/

I have found the property '_uninflected' in the documention, but I don't think it's what I'm looking for (nor will it work for what I want).

Comment: `this_is_an_/example/` would of course resolve to the two parameters `this_is_an_` and `example` through the router. Is this really what you want?

Comment: In short, no, you cannot exclude characters. You should implement your own slugging function if you need that. I recommend using `iconv` if you can, as it's much faster.

Comment: @deceze, the routing is done by something else then CakePHP, and in the current situation, yes, this is what I want to accomplish.

Comment: @jeremyharris Thanks. Well then I'll implement my own slugging function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an explode and the slug each token.

```
$input='/hi/im/a/non inflected ùrl/:=D';
$tokens=explode('/',$input);
foreach($tokens as &$token) $token=Inflector::slug($token);
$output='this_is_an_'.implode('/',$tokens);
```

Comment: Comes close to what I'm currently using. I'm replacing slashes with a placeholder string, which I replace again with slashes after slugging it. I'm accepting this is as being the correct answer, as there appears to be no real 'valid' solution.